# Apple Rejection of application due to in app purchase

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

I had created one application with 2 versions one is paid second free.
Now in free application my some of features are showing an alert by telling the user 
"For using this feature you have to purchase Full Version. Do want to purchase?"

On click of No nothing done just dismiss the alert and user can continue with other available features.

On click of Yes I am navigating user on my application's link in app store. My application enter in background and AppStore opens. That shows my application. From there user can purchase app and can download app.

Apple rejected my free version application with following reason:

`11.13 Apps that link to external mechanisms for purchases or subscriptions to be used in the app, such as a “buy" button that goes to a web site to purchase a digital book, will be rejected.`

1) Am I doing is wrong?

2) Can I use in app purchase in the manner that my free version application get removed and full version get available? because logic for both application is different.

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only way to be sure is to ask Apple.

I would interpret what you've said as:

Going to the App Store to purchase the full version of your app is acceptible. Many apps (including mine) do just that.

However, using IAP to perform the upgrade might be preferable. Your main problem is transitioning existing users from the Lite/Full apps to one with IAP -- in short there's no fool-proof way of doing it.

One thing that might get you rejected is non-functional buttons in the free app. According to the guide-lines, all apps need to be fully functional. Of course your free version can have fewer features, but they don't like it when there are buttons that do nothing but prompt you to upgrade.

Answer (score 7):

You can't disable features in lite versions.  For example, if your lite version has a button that says "Level 5", the user clicks it, and it tells them to buy the full version, the app will be rejected.  However, if you have a button that says "Get the full version for more levels," that should be acceptable.

Answer (score 4):

What you are doing here is not in-app purchase. In-app purchase refers to using the iOS SDK to allow a user to purchase additional content or functionality that will run in your app. Having 2 separate versions of the app like that does not use in-app purchase.

I'm guessing your app was rejected because you gave the appearance of in-app purchasing by having a message saying "For using this feature you have to purchase Full Version. Do want to purchase?" What you should be able to do, without significant change, is disable those buttons that aren't available in the free version; perhaps replace their text with "Full Version Only." Then, somewhere else in the app, maybe the home screen or screen where those buttons are, you can have a button that says "Get the full version!" or something, which would link to your full version in the store.